# Is there a Muslim equivalent of Christian Science?

Tags: christianity, health

Christian Science is a sect encouraging medical neglect, and lobbying for laws making faith-healing exceptions to laws against medical neglect. I am interested, is there something similar in Islam?

Comment: Christian Science might be misread as science about Christianity. I assume you are instead referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Science ?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49644